# DirectShow media subtype for MP3?

Tags: c++, winapi, audio, mp3, directshow

What the media subtype for MP3 in DirectShow, equal MEDIASUBTYPE_MP3 or ... ?

```
pMediaType->SetType(&MEDIATYPE_Audio);
pMediaType->SetSubtype(&MEDIASUBTYPE_MP3);
```

But MEDIASUBTYPE_MP3 not exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MEDIASUBTYPE_MP3` is not defined as an identifier even though `WMMEDIASUBTYPE_MP3` is.

The subtype is [generic FourCC subtype](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375802) of type 0x55:

```
// 00000055-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71            WMMEDIASUBTYPE_MP3 
EXTERN_GUID(WMMEDIASUBTYPE_MP3, 
0x00000055, 0x0000, 0x0010, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0xAA, 0x00, 0x38, 0x9B, 0x71);
```

0x55 is coming from:

```
#define  WAVE_FORMAT_MPEGLAYER3                 0x0055 /* ISO/MPEG Layer3 Format Tag */
```

When in doubt, use [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) to render a relevant file and review the media types:

[image]